# Java - Set Color by switch case function

Tags: java, android, colors

I want to set the color of the TextView by the function getColor(). I tried a lot of different ways but I can't get it working. My code doesn't compile.

```
import java.awt.*;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class test extends Activity {

TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

text1.setTextColor(getcolorss(1));

public Color getColor(int x) {
   switch(x) {
       case 1: return Color.BLUE; 
       case 2: return Color.RED;
   } 
}

}
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Please include what is not working, the code given looks like it does not compile. Why does this not compile is quite different from my text color does not change when I run this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Looking at [`android.graphics.Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html), `RED`, `BLUE` etc are merely `int` constants. Therefore, we can have something like this:

```
int[] pallete = { Color.BLUE, Color.RED };
```

Then simply:

```
return pallete[x];
```

This will naturally `throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `x` is out of bounds. You can check for it and do something else if that's what you want. Note that arrays in Java is 0-based, meaning that given the above declaration:

```
pallete[0] == Color.BLUE
pallete[1] == Color.RED
```

The original code uses 1-based indexing, so if you need to, you can do simple translation:

```
return pallete[x-1];
```

Comment: Thank you thats what i want. But now he marks me "Color.BLUE" and "Color.RED" and give me the error message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Color". Why? Do i need more imports?

Comment: @Simon: I just checked the documentation and `Color.BLUE` is an `int`, so we need an `int[]` instead. I've fixed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like that since if you call getcolorss(3) there's no return statment.
Try either:

```
public Color getcolorss(int x)
{
 switch(x)
 {
  case 1: return Color.BLUE; 
  case 2: return Color.RED;
  default: return null;
 } 
}
```

or

```
public Color getcolorss(int x)
{
 Color result = null;
 switch(x)
 {
  case 1: result = Color.BLUE; 
  case 2: result = Color.RED;
 }
 // this allows you to do something else here, if you require something more complex
 return result;
}
```